# How can I get a string from NSData and vice versa to send through QR code?

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, qr-code

I need to send encrypted data through my QR code so I have encrypted some text. I wish to send string of this encrypted data through QR code to another device which can decrypt it. I am having trouble even getting the string from the encrypted data. I assume maybe encrypted data cannot be string (nil) so how can I transfer the data through QR code? Here is me trying to get string of the encrypted data:

```
let data = (message as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!

        if let encryptedData = testCrypt(data, keyData:keyData, ivData:ivData, operation:UInt32(kCCEncrypt)) {
            let stringFromData = NSString(data: encryptedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("stringFromData = \(stringFromData)") // nil
}
```

Here is function:

```
func testCrypt(data:NSData, keyData:NSData, ivData:NSData, operation:CCOperation) -> NSData? {
        let keyBytes = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(keyData.bytes)            
        let ivBytes = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(ivData.bytes)
        let dataLength = Int(data.length)
        let dataBytes  = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes)

        let cryptData: NSMutableData! = NSMutableData(length: Int(dataLength) + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
        let cryptPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(cryptData.mutableBytes)
        let cryptLength  = size_t(cryptData.length)

        let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)
        let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
        let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

        var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

        let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                  algoritm,
                                  options,
                                  keyBytes, keyLength,
                                  ivBytes,
                                  dataBytes, dataLength,
                                  cryptPointer, cryptLength,
                                  &numBytesEncrypted)

        if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
            cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)

        } else {
            print("Error: \(cryptStatus)")
        }

        return cryptData;
    }
```

Another solution I tried was to interpolate the NSData into string. This worked however I am stuck trying to get the string back to the NSData on the receiving end of WR code. I have the code to encrypt/decrypt I just need to figure out how to send the encrypted data over the QR code somehow. Here is my interpolation:

```
let data = (message as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!

            if let encryptedData = testCrypt(data, keyData:keyData, ivData:ivData, operation:UInt32(kCCEncrypt)) {
                let stringFromData = "\(encryptedData)"
                print("\(stringFromData)") // correct
    }
```

Comment: You will probably want to convert your encrypted data to a printable format such as base64

Comment: @Paulw11 I am not really sure how to do that :S

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1413546-base64encodedstring

Comment: let base64String = encryptedData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0)) that got me a string that isn't nil thank you. So assuming this is string I would pass through QR code, how would I transfer this string back into NSData it came from?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1410081-init

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much !